# Consider $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n^2}I_{[0,n]}(x).$ Discuss the following relations...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $I_A(x)$ be the function that is 1 if $x$ is in $A$ and 0 elsewhere. \ Let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n^2}I_{[0,n]}(x).$
{problem}
      \item a) For each $x,$ find $\ds{\lim_{n\to\infty}}f_n(x).$ Define the previous number as $f(x).$
      \item b) Find a formula for $f(x),$ therefore $f_n {{ptwise \atop \longrightarrow} \atop \ }  f.$
      \item c) For each $n,$ find $\ds{\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\, dx}$
      \item d) Find $\ds{\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(x)\, dx}$
      \item e) Find $\ds{\int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx}.$ \  Does this answer match the previous one?
    \end
 \end{problem}

a) The answer is 0 - for x in A, 1/x^2 goes to zero. And for x not in A, f_n = 0.

b) Not sure how to start this one.

c) For each n, the integral evaluates to 1/n.

d) Given c, the limit is 0.

e) Not sure how start this one.

Submitting my thoughts for criticism/guidance! Thanks!

Comment: As stated, you've essentially answered all the parts (the formula for part (b) is f(x)=0, as you've shown in part (a), and thus in part (e) its integral is zero as well).  However, I suspect there is a typo somewhere: I'm guessing the problem you want is actually for $f_n(x)=n^2 I_{[0,1/n]}(x)$ (or something similar), as the answer in this case is much more interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your response! No, there is no typo!